# Не полностью заполняется JFrame, JPanel используя GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

[image: JFrame]

Как убрать отступы в JFrame которые изображены на картинке.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    JLabel a[]=new JLabel[1200];
    JButton b[]=new JButton[1200];
    Snake(){
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(30,40));

        ImageIcon X = new ImageIcon(Snake.class.getResource("1.jpg"));

        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            a[i]=new JLabel();
            a[i].setSize(10,10);
            a[i].setIcon(X);
            panel.add(a[i]);

        }
       frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Попробуйте поставить на `GridLayout`: `layout.setVgap(0);`

Comment: К сожалению не решило проблему.

Comment: А если поставить перед `setVilible(true)` такую строку: `frame.pack()`?

Comment: Места не хватает, т.к. размеры frame включают в себя еще рамку и заголовок, `frame.pack()` действительно должен помочь

Comment: почему то вообще окно принимает минимальное значение, то есть кроме шапки ничего не видно

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед строкой `frame.setVisible(true);` добавить строку:

```
 frame.pack();
```

Comment: почему то вообще окно принимает минимальное значение, то есть кроме шапки ничего не видно